# How to get Crystal Reports to show bulleted Lists

Tags: c#, mysql, vb.net, crystal-reports, rtf

How can I get bulleted lists using Crystal Reports 2008 Developer version with Visual Studio 2010 and vb.net.  The report is based on a MySQL database with various fields placed in RTF Textboxes. I know that I can create a formula consisting of chr(110) using the Wingding font for static test. However, I need to able to select a paragraph and add a bullet character to each line within the paragraph which does work with the RTF textbox. However, Crystal ignores the bullets.

I've seen a number of these issues reported but haven't found a suitable work-around.  Seems as if this problem dates back to the early releases of Crystal so I'm surprised I'm not finding a good work-around.  Actually I'm more surprised that after all of the Crystal Reports versions it hasn't been fixed.

The code I'm using in the RTF Textbox to set the bullet is:

```
If RTB1.SelectionBullet = False Then
    RTB1.SelectionIndent = 20
    RTB1.BulletIndent = 10
    RTB1.SelectionBullet = True

Else
    RTB1.SelectionBullet = True
End If
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Problem Resolved.

I discovered some great vb.net routines to add both numbered bullets and special bullets.  Here's a link to the code:

http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_net_special_bullet_rtf.html

Vic